# Does C++ guarantee the order of operands in comparisons made by standard containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unordered-set

TL;DR: I have a use case where it matters whether `WidgetEqualTo()(new_widget, widget_inside_container)` or `WidgetEqualTo()(widget_inside_container, new_widget)` is called.

Identical Widgets may be re-created many times so I have a `WidgetPool` (for the purposes of this example, a global wrapper around `std::vector<const Widget*>`) and a smart constructor:

```
const Widget* combine(const Widget* a, const Widget* b) {
  static std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int> cache;
  std::pair<int, int> ab = std::make_pair(a->id(), b->id());
  const auto it = cache.find(ab);
  if (it == cache.end()) {
    // The Widget ctor sets this->id() to WidgetPool::size()
    // and appends this to WidgetPool.
    const Widget* result = new Widget(a, b);
    cache[ab] = result->id();
    return result;
  } else {
    return WidgetPool::get_widget(it->second);
  }
}
```

I also have a container where Widgets get inserted in the order of their creation.  Say, `std::unordered_set<const Widget*, WidgetHash, WidgetEqualTo>`, where `WidgetEqualTo` looks like this:

```
struct WidgetEqualTo {
  bool operator()(const Widget* a, const Widget* b) const {
    if (a == b) {
      return true;
    }
    // My Widgets obey the associative law:
    // tedious_comparison(new Widget(new Widget(p, q), r),
    //                    new Widget(p, new Widget(q, r))) == true.
    const bool are_equal = tedious_comparison(a, b);
    if (are_equal) {
      // Cache the result of the comparison.
      // Retain the older Widget.
      if (a->id() < b->id()) {  // (***)
        WidgetPool::set_widget(b->id(), a);
        delete b;
      } else {
        WidgetPool::set_widget(a->id(), b);
        delete a;
      }
    }
    return are_equal;
  }
};
```

If `WidgetEqualTo()` were always called with `(new_element, element_already_inside_unordered_set)` or the other way around, I could remove one branch of the test marked with `(***)`.  FWIW, libstdc++ appears to call `WidgetEqualTo()(new_element, old_element)`.  Does the C++ standard guarantee this behavior?

Comment: See the [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept. I suspect you will not satisfy all of the requirements listed.

Comment: not sure what you are doing there, but I have the impression that everything after `are_equal = tedious_comparison()` shouldnt be done inside a comparator

Comment: It's not clear to me why your comparator is also responsible for modifying your pool.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth There are two hard things in computer programming.  Cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.  You can see the OP doing a cache invalidation in a const operation as an example of the insanely bad code that demonstrates why doing it well is hard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

> `[C++11: 25.2.5/3]:` Each unordered associative container is parameterized by `Key`, by a function object type `Hash` that meets the `Hash` requirements (17.6.3.4) and acts as a hash function for argument values of type `Key`, and by **a binary predicate `Pred` that induces an equivalence relation on values of type `Key`**. Additionally, `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap` associate an arbitrary mapped type `T` with the `Key`.

Table 17 tells us the `EqualityComparable` requirements:

> `==` is an equivalence relation, that is, it has the following properties:
>
> - For all `a`, `a == a`.
> - **If `a == b`, then `b == a`.**
> - If `a == b` and `b == c`, then `a == c`.

<sup>*(gah! comma splice!)*</sup>

And note that the given semantics of the comparator makes no mention of which way around the operands are given:

> `[C++11: 25.2.5/5]:` Two values `k1` and `k2` of type `Key` are considered equivalent if the container’s `key_equal` function object returns `true` when passed those values. *[..]*

Put simply, your program has undefined behaviour if it matters which order the arguments are supplied.

This is not a C++ oddity, either; [equivalence implies symmetry throughout mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Comment: +1 for this is more than C++; even if C++ let you do an antisymmetric `==`, it is a bad plan for the same reason as implmenting `<` but not `>` usually is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit  Thank you.  I can live with the `(***)` test.  There are other pretty natural assumptions in my code:  1) that `key_equal()` won't be called anymore once it returns `true` for a given key we try to insert;  2) that `insert()` never replaces a key with a key equal to it.  Can I make them?

Comment: @MarcinCiura: Please do ask followup questions as new questions :) Feel free to ping me a link